# Python Pulp - Unable to Model Non-Square Matrix

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am having issues with setting up constraints using both input arrays from excel and variable arrays within PULP.

**It appears the model only works with square matrices and my final code has a matrix that is 365x24.  The code below has a matrix of 5x6 and throws an error when running saying index out of range.**

I have provided the code that I am working with so far.

Sheet11 Matrix

```
91  37  36  38  33  16
1   36  59  29  23  4
25  74  72  39  69  1
22  68  48  70  12  41
98  86  75  16  99  12
```

Sheet12 Matrix

```
59  63  66  57  4   15
26  33  75  71  21  2
37  88  89  1   90  3
91  48  27  24  23  14
68  13  61  37  77  20
```

```
from pulp import *
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd

model = pulp.LpProblem("Basic Model", pulp.LpMinimize)

YPER = 5
HE = 6

yearlyhours = []
yearlyhours = [(i,j) for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE)]

book = xlrd.open_workbook('Stack.xlsx')
sheet11 = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet11')
sheet12 = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet12')
sheet13 = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet13')

TEST = [[sheet11.cell_value(i,j) for i in range(YPER)] for j in range(HE)]
YAPR = [[sheet12.cell_value(i,j) for i in range(YPER)] for j in range(HE)]
MAPR = [[sheet13.cell_value(i,j) for i in range(YPER)] for j in range(HE)]

YAHL = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("YAHL", (range(YPER), range(HE)), lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
MAHL = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("MAHL", (range(YPER), range(HE)), lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

##OBJECTIVE##
model += pulp.lpSum([YAPR[i][j] * YAHL[i][j] + MAPR[i][j] * MAHL[i][j] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE)]), 'Sum_of_Value'

for i,j in yearlyhours:
    model += pulp.lpSum([YAHL[i][j] + MAHL[i][j]]) == ([TEST[i][j]])

LpSolverDefault.msg = 1
model.writeLP('Opt.lp')
model.solve()
pulp.LpStatus[model.status]
print("Status:", LpStatus[model.status])
obj = value(model.objective)
print("Total Cost: ${}".format(obj,2))
print('\n')
```

When changing to a non-square matrix the following error message is given:

IndexError: list index out of range

Any help appreciated as I am still learning.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might consider asking on [OR.SE] (or.stackexchange.com).

Comment: From the sounds of the error message you are trying to reference an element beyond the end of a list. Find out which line is throwing that error and then print out the size of the list, and the max index you are referencing. Keep in mind python is zero-indexed so the last element of a 5-element list is element [4].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to read in the data produces 6 rows and 5 columns. The variable dictionary structure is 5 keys and then the inner dict has six keys. So when you try to iterate over both simultaneously, you get an index error. The square matrix works because 5 x 5 is the same as 5 x 5, so the reversed order doesn't matter.

```
>>>YAHL
{
 0: {
   0: YAHL_0_0,                                                                                                         
   1: YAHL_0_1,                                                                                                            
   2: YAHL_0_2,                                                                                                            
   3: YAHL_0_3,                                                                                                            
   4: YAHL_0_4,                                                                                                            
   5: YAHL_0_5
 },                                                                                                          ...                                                                                                          4: {
  0: YAHL_4_0,                                                                                                         
  1: YAHL_4_1,                                                                                                            
  2: YAHL_4_2,                                                                                                            
  3: YAHL_4_3,                                                                                                            
  4: YAHL_4_4,                                                                                                            
  5: YAHL_4_5}} 
 }
}
>>>TEST
[[91.0, 1.0, 25.0, 22.0, 98.0],
 [37.0, 36.0, 74.0, 68.0, 86.0],
 [36.0, 59.0, 72.0, 48.0, 75.0],
 [38.0, 29.0, 39.0, 70.0, 16.0],
 [33.0, 23.0, 69.0, 12.0, 99.0],
 [16.0, 4.0, 1.0, 41.0, 12.0]]

>>>for i in range(YPER):
       for j in range(HE):
           print(TEST[i][j])
           print(YAHL[i][j])
91.0
YAHL_0_0
1.0
YAHL_0_1
25.0
YAHL_0_2
22.0
YAHL_0_3
98.0
YAHL_0_4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-a9538e188b1e> in <module>
      1 for i in range(YPER):
      2     for j in range(HE):
----> 3         print(TEST[i][j])
      4         print(YAHL[i][j])
      5

IndexError: list index out of range
```